# Autoinstaller from list of packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wonder if there is some service which saves all your package/repositories list in a Cloud, so that when reinstalling the OS you just can install everything at once in one command line.

Does it exist something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of. Though you could create a small script that does that and keep it in dropbox or a similar cloud storage solution.

Something along these lines should work. Careful about missing dependencies though.

`sudo apt-get --ignore-missing install $package.list`

Where package.list is a text file with a list of everything you want to install. You can use the same logic to add repos.

`sudo add-apt-repository $repo.links`

Comment: thanks. I've found an option in the Software Center that says 'Sync between another computers', and ask you to create an Ubuntu account. Is this something similar?

Comment: `dpkg --get-selection > package.list` is another option I read

Comment: how do I get the package list instead?

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep "^ii"| awk ' {print $2} ' > package.list`

Comment: ok, that would retrieve all the packages, but I think I'm really interested on the ones I've installed only. Supposing I need to use that backup on another ubuntu based distribution.